# What happens? <= on two varchars?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In my Oracle db, I noticed some strange behavior when doing a <= comparison on two numbers. And I found the problem. The .net code was passing in one of the values as a DbParameter of type string. And the Oracle column type of the other number was a varchar. So essentially what was happening was a <= on two numbers that were actually varchars.

**Can someone explain why the following statement is true in PLSQL?**

```
'10000001' <= '50000'
```

Comment: 1 sorts before 5 ASCIIabetically.

Comment: This is a string comparison which acts differently than a number comparison.

Comment: See the [data type comparison](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF30027) rules, which explain what is happening. Basically, `’1’` is “less than“ `’5’` when compared as characters in your character set.

Comment: If only there was more than thirty years' worth of database practice emphasising the importance of using the appropriate datatype for the data.

Comment: It's not just true in PL/SQL, it's true in SQL, and, I would think, in all languages that distinguish between strings and numbers. Why wouldn't `'1'` be less than `'5'`?

Answer (score 1):

Becuase-

```
SQL> select ascii('10000001') from dual;

ASCII('10000001')
-----------------
               49

SQL> select ascii('50000') from dual;

ASCII('50000')
--------------
            53

SQL> select 'true' from dual where ascii('10000001') < ascii('50000');

'TRU
----
true
```